# AfterUpdate for few textboxes in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I would like to know that it is possible to make function AfterUpdate for few textboxes? I have 10 textboxes and write the same definition for all is usefull. Is any solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes, possible. Write codes for specific textboxes `After Update` events.

Comment: I don't know how I can write it for few textboxes together. I know only how for each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a

```
Private Function MyAfterUpdate()
    ' stuff
End Function
```

in your form module.

Then, instead of `[Event Procedure]`, put `=MyAfterUpdate()` in the `After Update` properties of the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what *WithEvents* is for, one of Access' hidden gems.

An example can be found in my project: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

Code is too much to post here, though, so peruse the demo. It handles the *OnClick* event of labels, but you can easily change that to deal with *AfterUpdate* of texboxes - or any other event of other controls for that matter.